# form validation in nest js using class validator is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nestjs

hello guys i was tring to validate an incoming form data using the class validator package and dto
here is my dto,

```
import { IsString, IsPhoneNumber, IsEnum, MinLength } from 'class-validator';


export class CreateAgentDto {
  @IsString()
  firstName: string;

  @IsString()
  middleName: string;

  @IsString()
  lastName: string;

  @IsString()
  @MinLength(6)
  password: string;
 
  gender: string;

  @IsPhoneNumber()
  @MinLength(10)
  phone: string;

  @IsString()
  @MinLength(4)
  username: string;

  @IsString()
  userId: string;

  agentType: string;

  @IsString()
  country: string;

  @IsString()
  state: string;

  @IsString()
  city: string;

  propertySize?: string;
}
```

and here is my controller

```
@Post('register')
  @UseInterceptors(FileFieldsInterceptor([
  {name: 'id', maxCount:1},
  { name: 'tradePermission', maxCount: 1 },
  ]))
  async register(
    @Body(ValidationPipe) body: CreateAgentDto,
    @UploadedFiles(
     
    ) files: { id?: Express.Multer.File[], tradePermission?: Express.Multer.File[] },
  ) {
    console.log(body)
}
```

if i didnt use the validation pipe the `console.log(body)` produces

```
[Object: null prototype] {
  nonFileData: '{"firstName":"kebede","middleName":"sdsds","lastName":"lemma","username":"yoo11","password":"yoo11","gender":"male","phone":"0924654112","country":"ET","state":"ET-DD","city":"DIRE DAWA|ET-DD","agentType":"simple","propertySize":"","userId":"inkele123768"}'
}
```

but when i use the validator the apis response will be
[image the apis response when used with the validation pipe in postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFJZf.png)

Comment: Can you try putting the relevant text from the response in the message instead of an image. Also mention what you believe is wrong with the response your getting and what the result would be if it is what you want.

Answer (score 3):

`nonFileData` property is not part of `CreateAgentDto` definition. Your `register` method is expecting a request that looks like this:

```
    curl --location --request POST '' \
    --form 'firstName="foo"' \
    --form 'middleName="baaar"' \
    --form 'lastName="xxxx"'
```

but you are sending something like this:

```
     curl --location --request POST '' \
     --form 'nonFileData="{\"firstName\":\"foo\",\"middleName\":\"bar\"}"' \
```

Also  neither `CreateAgentDto` has the `id` nor `tradePermission` properties that you are using in the file interceptor to get the file.